# How can I get the multiple columns in a single row using MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I want combine mutiple rows columns as single record in MySQL

For eg: Actual Data

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
     id         name          Loantype        Amount
--------------------------------------------------------------
     1          ABC              1            500000
     2          ABC              2            3500000
     3          XYZ              1            250000
     4          XYZ              2            2500000
```

I tried with the following query

```
SELECT
    id,
    (
        CASE Loantype
            WHEN 1 THEN Amount
            ELSE NULL
        END
    ) AS PersonalLoan,
    (
        CASE Loantype
            WHEN 2 THEN Amount
            ELSE NULL
        END
    ) AS HomeLoan
FROM
    customer
WHERE
    name = 'ABC'
```

but result comes as below

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
     id         name          PersonalLoan    HomeLoan
--------------------------------------------------------------
     1          ABC            500000         NULL
     1          ABC            NULL         2500000
```

Expected Result set

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
     id         name          PersonalLoan    HomeLoan
--------------------------------------------------------------
     1          ABC            500000         3500000
```

Comment: What happens if the same customer has multiple loans of the same `LoanType`? Or is there a constraint to prevent that happening?

Comment: Which column is used to join rows? Is it name?

Comment: @SoloOmsarashvili No `JOIN` is necessary.

Comment: @Dai How would you identify connection between two rows. As I understood his case, he wants to join rows where additional columns (PersonalLoan and HomeLoan) are filled based on LoanType

Comment: @SoloOmsarashvili See my answer, which does not use a `JOIN`, it uses a `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can self-join the table so that you will be able to combine the 2 kinds of loans into single row:

```sql
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.amount AS personal, t2.amount AS home
FROM customer AS t1
LEFT JOIN customer AS t2 ON t1.name = t2.name AND t2.loantype = 2
WHERE t1.loantype = 1
```

If you are looking for just 1 user - you can speedup the query by limiting the size of the JOIN:

```sql
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.amount AS personal, t2.amount AS home
FROM (SELECT * FROM customer WHERE name = "ABC" AND loantype = 1) AS t1
LEFT JOIN customer AS t2 ON t1.name = t2.name AND t2.loantype = 2
```

Comment: Your query doesn't work if a customer has rows with `loantype = 2` but doesn't have any rows with `loantype = 1`. It will also return `home = NULL` instead of `home = 0` if a customer has a `loantype = 1` but not any rows with `loantype = 2` (though that may be desirable in this case).

Comment: @Dai You are right. But without enough information in the question - we can only guess about the needs or intentions of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

- Note that generally speaking you shouldn't denormalize data in SQL (e.g. converting rows to columns: SQL is row-oriented, not column-oriented) - I assume this is to simplify display logic - just be careful of using queries like this when you want to pass *meaningful data* to other parts of the database rather than directly to the user.
- You need to `GROUP BY` first.
- You can also simplify your `CASE` expressions:
  `ELSE NULL` is always implicit and if the `CASE WHEN` expression is an equality comparison then you can use the simpler switch-style syntax.

  - So `CASE WHEN a = b THEN c ELSE NULL END` can be simplified to `CASE a WHEN b THEN c END`.
- I've added `COALESCE` so the query will return `0` for the `SUM` aggregates if there are no matching rows instead of `NULL`. Note that `COUNT` (unlike `SUM`) generally doesn't need to be wrapped in a `COALESCE` (though I forget precisely how MySQL handles this - it also depends on what version of MySQL you're using and what strict-mode and ANSI/ISO-compliance options are enabled).

---

- Note that the database design you posted seems to allow the same `customer.name` to have multiple loans of the same `loantype`.

  - You can avoid this by adding a  `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` or `UNIQUE INDEX` or use a Composite Primary Key:

    - `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UX_name_loantype ON customer ( name, loantype )`
  - To prevent those rows from causing issues in this query, this uses a `SUM` and a `COUNT` to make it clear to readers that the data is an aggregate over multiple rows:

```
SELECT
    name,
    
    COUNT( CASE Loantype WHEN 1 THEN 1 END ) AS CountPersonalLoans,
    COALESCE( SUM( CASE Loantype WHEN 1 THEN Amount END ), 0 ) AS SumPersonalLoans,

    COUNT( CASE Loantype WHEN 2 THEN 1 END ) AS CountHomeLoans,
    COALESCE( SUM( CASE Loantype WHEN 2 THEN Amount END ), 0 ) AS SumHomeLoans

FROM
    customer
GROUP BY
    name
```

To maximise query code reuse if you want to filter by `name` then convert this to a `VIEW` - or if it's a one-off then make it a `CTE` query, like so:

```
WITH aggs AS (
    SELECT
        name,
        
       COUNT( CASE Loantype WHEN 1 THEN 1 END ) AS CountPersonalLoans,
        COALESCE( SUM( CASE Loantype WHEN 1 THEN Amount END ), 0 ) AS SumPersonalLoans,

        COUNT( CASE Loantype WHEN 2 THEN 1 END ) AS CountHomeLoans,
        COALESCE( SUM( CASE Loantype WHEN 2 THEN Amount END ), 0 ) AS SumHomeLoans

    FROM
        customer
    GROUP BY
        name
)
SELECT
    name,
    CountPersonalLoans,
    SumPersonalLoans,
    CountHomeLoans,
    SumHomeLoans
FROM
    aggs
WHERE
    name = 'ABC'
ORDER BY
    name
```

Comment: CASE without THEN is not a valid syntax.

Comment: @IVOGELOV Thanks! Good catch. Fixing now.